# How to Create a FolderName Variable in PowerShell that equals an Exact Name

Tags: powershell, variables, get-childitem

I am working on a script that basically looks for a folder name and then recurses through the folder structure finding files with a specific extension and then delete those files older than X amount of days, then output the results into a CSV file.

```
# *IMPORTANT* DOUBLE CHECK
$fileType = '*.dwg'
$foldername = "Site Plans"

# *IMPORTANT* DOUBLE CHECK - Get the current date and calculate the date -XX days ago
$currentDate = Get-Date
$cutOffDate = $currentDate.AddDays(-1)

### START SCRIPT ### 
#$path = "C:\Users\zbarchuk\desktop\Site Plans - Copy"
$path = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $foldername}

# Get Top Folder Name from path
#$pathTopFolder = ($path).split("\")[-1]

# $PSScriptRoot is the current path to the script ****
$GetDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss"

# File Stats
$log = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@("FileName, FilePath, FileSize")
$TotalSize = 0

# Get all files with the .pdf extension that are older than 45 days in all directories and subdirectories
$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter $fileType | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutOffDate }

# Get File Item Count
$count = 1
$fileCount = @($filesToDelete).Count

# Delete each file
$OutputLog = @()
foreach ($file in $filesToDelete) {
    
    #Get Item Size and add to file array
    $size=[math]::Round((Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName).length/1MB,2)

    
    Write-Progress -Activity $count"/"$fileCount
    #Write-Host -Activity "Deleting " $file.FullName

    #Calc total size of deleted files
    $TotalSize = ($TotalSize + $size)
    
    #Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force
    $count = $count+1

    $OutputLog+=@([PSCustomObject]@{
        FileName = $file
        FilePath = Split-Path -Parent ($file.FullName)
        FileSize = "$size" + " MB"
    })
    
}

$OutputLog+=@([PSCustomObject]@{
        FileName = "Total PDF File Cleanup Size"
        FilePath = "Total Items=$fileCount"
        FileSize = "$TotalSize MB"
    })

$OutputLog | Export-CSv -Path C:\users\zbarchuk\desktop\CleanupOutputLog.csv
```

The issue I am running into and can't seem to figure out is the $path Get-ChildItem code is grabbing all folders with a similar name to the one I am looking for. I have tried various iterations using -Unique -Eq -Match but nothing seems to set it to only look for that specific folder name. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $foldername}` returns 1 item or nothing. Have you double check that you're getting the folder you expect as output? If so the issue is here: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path` and changing that to `$path | Get-ChildItem` will likely solve the problem

Comment: I do in fact get the folder I am looking for, but there are other folder names that are similar in the directory that are getting picked up. I tried altering the `Get-ChildItem -Path $path` to what you suggested but looks like I am getting no results this time when I open up the exported CSV file. `$filesToDelete = $path | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter $fileType | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutOffDate }`

Comment: Try adding -Directory option to get only directories.   You may be getting files and directories.

Comment: @user23628294 The argument to the `-Filter` parameter is passed to Windows' internal file system enumeration API which treats the filter string `*.<exactly-three-letters>` as a special edge case which returns anything matching `*.dwg*`. Does that sound like what's happening here? I can't help but notice the comment above the `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter $fileType` says `# Get all files with the .pdf extension [...]` - are you getting extra files with extensions that match `*.pdf*`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, filtering on the extension appears to work as you describe in Windows PowerShell, but not in PowerShell Core (7.4.1).

Comment: @user23628294 Yes that is what it was intended for and I am getting `*.dwg` files when this is run. We were originally using PDF's as a tester but then modified it for dwgs, I forgot to update that part of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code takes into account that there could be multiple `Site Plans` directories. It also omits the summary totals in favor of doing it from the log file after completion.

The `Remove-Item` command is used, but it has `-WhatIf` which will cause it to only report what it would do. This allows you to safely run the script many times without deleting any files.

```
# *IMPORTANT* DOUBLE CHECK
$fileType = '.dwg'
$foldername = "Site Plans"

# *IMPORTANT* DOUBLE CHECK - Get the current date and calculate the date -XX days ago
$currentDate = Get-Date
$cutOffDate = $currentDate.AddDays(-1)

### START SCRIPT ### 
$paths = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path 'C:\' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $foldername}
$filestodelete = @()

foreach ($path in $paths) {
    # Get all files with the $filetype extension that are older than 45 days in all directories and subdirectories
    $filesToDelete += Get-ChildItem -File -Path $path -Recurse |
        Where-Object { ($_.Extension -eq $filetype) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutOffDate) }
}

# Get File Item Count
$count = 1
$fileCount = $filesToDelete.Count

# Delete each file
$OutputLog = @()
foreach ($file in $filesToDelete) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "$count/$fileCount"
    Write-Information "Deleting $($file.FullName)"

    # Remove the file
    Remove-Item $file.FullName -Force -Whatif
    $count++

    $OutputLog += [PSCustomObject]@{
        FileName = $file.Name
        FilePath = $file.DirectoryName
        FileSize = $file.Length
    }
}

$LogFileFullName = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'CleanupOutputLog.csv'
$OutputLog | Export-Csv -Path $LogFileFullName
```

After producing the log file, generate the count and size with:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\CleanupOutputLog.csv | Measure-Object -Sum FileSize
```

or

```
(Import-Csv -Path .\CleanupOutputLog.csv | Measure-Object -Sum FileSize).Sum / 1MB
```

Comment: You mention that the code takes into account that there could multiple Site Plan folders, how is that the case? Doesnt the line of code `$foldername = "Site Plans"` supposed to only look for what is in the quotes? Im still learning powershell so forgive me if this is a simple answer.

Comment: There could be `\src\JAN\Site Plans\` as well as `\src\FEB\Site Plans\` directories. The `Get-ChildItem` after the `### START SCRIPT ###` line finds them all.